# Imported const is null when function is called but not when logged

Tags: javascript, react-native

Trying to use [React Native Community Clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/clipboard). When using the `setClipboard` function like so:

```
import Clipboard from '@react-native-community/clipboard';

/*
  More code here
*/

Clipboard.setString("Hello");
```

I receive an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setString' of null
```

However, when logging `Clipboard` or even `Clipboard.setString`, I can see that it isn't null:

```
console.log(Clipboard.setString); // Outputs the log: [Function setString]
```

Even if I check the function exists first, I see the same error:

```
Clipboard.setString && Clipboard.setString("Hello"); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'setString' of null
```

How is it possible that the Clipboard object can be null *only* when I try to invoke a function? Is it possible that there's some overlap with something else in the repo I'm working in?

Answer (score 1):

There's some discussion [here](https://github.com/react-native-clipboard/clipboard/issues/71) that has a few solutions/workarounds.

A couple examples they mention are

use the hook instead:

`import {useClipboard} from '@react-native-community/clipboard';`

or possibly using Clipboard from react-native:

`import { Clipboard } from 'react-native';`

Hope one of these helps!

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion! I did try the hook actually but ran into a similar error: `Cannot read property 'getString' of null`. I guess this is just a known issue without a solution as of yet...

Comment: You could also try `cd android && ./gradlew clean` if you're using android or `cd ios && pod install` for ios, both were also mentioned as possible solutions